# Can't login to Laravel after authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I have a login problem where my authentication work, but after I redirect to the homepage, it didnt show anything.

**Controller**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $user = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];

    if (Auth::Attempt($user)) {
        return redirect('home');
    }
    
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Wrong Credential!');
}
```

**Home Blade**

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('title')
    Home
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>this is home</p>
    
    @if(Auth::check())
        test
    @endif

@endsection
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: You can't see the "test" message?

Comment: Yes. But when I replace "redirect('home')" with "Auth::check()" it will return boolean 1

Answer (score 0):

Based on Laravel documentation:[authenticating-users](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users)

The `attempt` method is normally used to handle authentication attempts from your application's "login" form. If authentication is successful, you should regenerate the user's session to prevent session fixation by adding:

```
$request->session()->regenerate();
```

```
public function login(Request $request){
        $user = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ];

       if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect('home');
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Wrong Credential!');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I try to login, it still didnt show "test" in my home blade.

Comment: did you try the example in the documentation ? `return redirect()->intended('home')` use (`intended`) method @WinerWijaya

Comment: sorry for late reply. I just tried it but still didnt work